# jQuery Retain DatePicker Date text into a textbox after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Retain DatePicker Date text into a textbox after postback,
I am trying hard to understand how to retain a DatePicker date into a textbox after postback.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#Arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date"
        
    });
});
```

```html
                            <input class="calendarr font" name="Arrival" readonly  type="text" id="Arrival" onchange="changedDate()">

<input type="submit" class="btns" value="Search"  />
```

I have tried with many options which did not work.

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks .

Comment: use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: @RohithKP do you have example with datepicker for local storage

Comment: @ahosam are you using updatepanels ?

Comment: @Webruster no i am using  mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //on submit
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("inputVal", $('calendarr').val());

    //on page load
    // Retrieve
    var storedVal = localStorage.getItem("inputVal");
    $('calendarr').val(storedVal);
```

Assuming you are using jquery UI datepicker.

```
//to store data on date change
    $("#Arrival").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).val();
             localStorage.setItem("inputVal", date);
        }
    });
```

To initially populate data from LS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#Arrival').datepicker("setDate", localStorage.getItem("inputVal") );
});
```

Comment: thanks, this is worked with me, but if i want data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab. i just replace localStorage iinstead of sessionStorage  ????

Comment: @ahosam there is no need to use session storage. But you have to update the `localStorage` whenever necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

**BEFORE POSTBACK (JAVASCRIPT)**

```
function changedDate() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("Arrival", $("#Arrival").val());
}

<input class="calendarr font" name="Arrival" readonly  type="text" id="Arrival" onchange="changedDate()">
```

**AFTER POST BACK (JAVASCRIPT)**

```
$("#Arrival").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Arrival");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your DatePicker as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

           Sys.Application.add_load(function () {

          $("#Arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date"

        });

           });

       });
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not worked the button_Image not display

Comment: @ahosam what do you mean by button_Image not display

Comment: i can not open datepicker to choose the date from datepicker